# Java getMethod with superclass parameters in method

Tags: java, reflection

Given:

```
class A
{
    public void m(List l) { ... }
}
```

Let's say I want to invoke method `m` with reflection, passing an ArrayList as the parameter to `m`:

```
List myList = new ArrayList();
A a = new A();
Method method = A.class.getMethod("m", new Class[] { myList.getClass() });
method.invoke(a, Object[] { myList });
```

The `getMethod` on line 3 will throw `NoSuchMethodException` because the runtime type of myList is ArrayList, not List.

Is there a good generic way around this that doesn't require knowledge of class A's parameter types?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

If you know the type is `List`, then use `List.class` as argument.

If you don't know the type in advance, imagine you have:

```
public void m(List l) {
 // all lists
}

public void m(ArrayList l) {
  // only array lists
}
```

Which method should the reflection invoke, if there is any automatic way?

If you want, you can use `Class.getInterfaces()` or `Class.getSuperclass()` but this is case-specific.

What you can do here is:

```
public void invoke(Object targetObject, Object[] parameters,
        String methodName) {
    for (Method method : targetObject.getClass().getMethods()) {
        if (!method.getName().equals(methodName)) {
            continue;
        }
        Class<?>[] parameterTypes = method.getParameterTypes();
        boolean matches = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < parameterTypes.length; i++) {
            if (!parameterTypes[i].isAssignableFrom(parameters[i]
                    .getClass())) {
                matches = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (matches) {
            // obtain a Class[] based on the passed arguments as Object[]
            method.invoke(targetObject, parametersClasses);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know the type in advance.  I would expect `m2` in your example if my l.getClass() returns ArrayList as the runtime type, but maybe I'm expecting too much?

Comment: exactly. But you want to execute the first method depending on whether the second exists or not. You can't do that.

Comment: So the only way to actually get `m1` would be try various permutations of the superclasses and interfaces for the various parameters which isn't a very good idea.

Comment: Exactly, you don't want to do all those permutations. In some very specific cases - .ie. you are building a framework or interpreter, or need to interface with (possibly badly written) p3rd party libraries, you need to do that. However, the resulting code is very brittle. Reflection is just another way to access artifacts defined by a class. In this case, the access is dynamic rather than statically compiled. But the requirements to know what you need to call remain the same.

Comment: I'll also add that if you truly do not know the actual type, and the requirements need you to operate without knowing that type of information, I'd say this: proceed with caution. In general, I would take such a situation like a *code (or requirement) smell*, something that needs revisiting.

Comment: @Bozho I think that's exactly what I need to do -- I have the name, so I won't have to check every method in the class, either.  Thanks!

Comment: +1 for the awesome reflection example, and pointing out the proper way to determine the correct method to call.

Answer (score 2):

See java.beans.Expression and java.beans.Statement.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `myList.getClass()`, why not just pass in `List.class`? That *is* what your method is expecting.

Comment: I don't actually have knowledge of exactly what method is being called.  There isn't just `m`, there are many methods with different parameter types.

Comment: You need to know a-priori what you are going to call. Reflection is not like magic. You need to what method name and method signature you want to access via reflection. Sometimes you also need to know what version of a method you need to call (.ie. you need to access the version of a method 'm' defined by one of your super classes.

Comment: @luis: I agree with your point saying reflection isn't going to help you choose a method, but I disagree that you need to know a-priori which exact method you are going to call. In an interpreter / dynamic language context, all you have is a method name, arguments, and if you're lucky you have some kind of hint from the user. The gap between the raw material provided by the reflection API and picking applicable methods based on argument types has to be provided by something at the interpreter application level.

Comment: @Jason in an interpreter/dynamic language context, you (probably) don't have method overloading, so you can (probably) figure out which method should be called just by the name.

Comment: @Matt: Huh? "Probably" doesn't get you very far: you *always* need to choose some action in case of overloading, whether it's pick the first method or fail in case of multiple methods of the same name. As far as delegating method overloading to the improbability heap, just take a look at methods/constructors of FileInputStream and File.

Comment: @Jason - my comment about needing to know the method a-priori is within the context of Java. Mentioning the reflection capabilities of an interpreter/dynamic language, though interesting in their own rights, are non sequitur to the context in which the OP's question was originally asked.

Comment: @luis: I can see your point within the context of Java, but how do you know the OP wasn't asking as an example of how to *implement* reflective invocation within Java to *expose* that ability outside of Java?

Comment: @Jason - Ahh, I don't. And neither do do. All we have is the OP's question (and his reply to Matt's question). In software, we should avoid making assumptions on requirements that are not being explicitly laid out. You go by what is explicitly expressed or what can be inferred reasonably. To assume the OP is looking for the capability you are referring to, as interesting as it might be, is just putting a spin on it a-la *petitio principii* to prop an argument that cannot be unequivocally inferred from the OP's post. I go by what is expressed in the question, nothing more.

Comment: @Jason - con't - not that I think it is not an interesting thing to discuss. It is simply that it doesn't follow from what has been explicitly asked. All we have is a bare-bone questions (without indicating intent or specific applicability) on an specific language (Java). That's the only context that is made available, and the rest, though mentally stimulating, is purely speculative.

Comment: fair enough. I made the assumption based upon the OP's statement about not knowing exact method argument ("parameter") types.

Comment: In this case, but more complex and dynamic cases show problems. In my case, i'm developing a short of framework which provides an operation "search and execute method" that accepts a list of Object as arguments. It is expected to find the most possible specific method available, but when there's no specific method declared for that subclass it should behave like normal java compiler and find the closest match. For instance, if we had m(Object), m(List) and m(ArrayList), ArrayList should trigger m(ArrayList), a custom Foo extends List to m(List) and anything that is not a list to m(Object)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you want `getDeclaredMethods()`. Here is an [example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.lang/ClassgetDeclaredMethods.htm). You can dig through the list of methods and pick the one you want by name. Whether or not this is robust or a good idea is another question.

Comment: Thanks, I did know about this but I didn't want to resort to it.  I might have to, though.