# Java: runtime method resolution

Tags: java, reflection, overload-resolution

I'm working on some dynamic invocation of code via an interpreter, and I'm getting into the sticky ugly areas of method resolution as discussed in [JLS section 15.12](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/expressions.html#15.12).

The "easy" way to choose a method is when you know the exact types of all the arguments, at which point you can use [`Class.getDeclaredMethod(String name, Class[] parameterTypes)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getDeclaredMethod%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%5B%5D%29). Maybe you have to check method accessibility and the class's superclasses/superinterfaces.

But this doesn't cover any of the following cases, so it's kind of useless:

- boxing/unboxing primitives
- subtypes
- varargs
- a null argument (which can be any type, unless the interpreter knows otherwise; at compile-time any ambiguity would be eliminating by casting null to a class/interface)
- primitive type conversion (not part of Java, but allowable in the context of languages -- e.g. Rhino Javascript where all numbers are floating-point, so the Java code might take an `int` but the caller passes in a number which is either an `int` or a `double`)

(see below for a quick example of the first three)

So now I have to write my own method resolution library...

**Is there any well-known framework library to assist in this?**

```
package com.example.test.reflect;

import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MethodResolutionTest {
    public void compute(int i)              { /* implementation... */ }
    public void compute(Long l)             { /* implementation... */ }
    public void compute(Object obj)         { /* implementation... */ }
    public void compute(String... strings)  { /* implementation... */ }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Class<?> cl = MethodResolutionTest.class;

        /* these succeed */
        findAndPrintMethod(cl, "compute", int.class);
        findAndPrintMethod(cl, "compute", Long.class);
        findAndPrintMethod(cl, "compute", Object.class);
        findAndPrintMethod(cl, "compute", String[].class);

        /* these fail */
        findAndPrintMethod(cl, "compute", Integer.class);
        findAndPrintMethod(cl, "compute", long.class);
        findAndPrintMethod(cl, "compute", MethodResolutionTest.class);
        findAndPrintMethod(cl, "compute", String.class, String.class);
    }
    private static void findAndPrintMethod(Class<?> objectClass, 
            String methodName, Class<?>... parameterTypes) 
    {
        try {
            Method method = findMethod(objectClass, methodName, 
                   parameterTypes);
            System.out.println(method.toString());
        }
        catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static Method findMethod(Class<?> objectClass, 
            String methodName, Class<?>[] parameterTypes) 
        throws SecurityException, NoSuchMethodException 
    {
        return objectClass.getDeclaredMethod(methodName, parameterTypes);
    }
}
```

Comment: [This answer handles some of your cases like subtypes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580665/java-getmethod-with-superclass-parameters-in-method/2580699#2580699).

Comment: @Jonathon: I know about isAssignableFrom. I got something homegrown working with subtypes and boxing/unboxing. Then I started into varargs and it got nasty, and I thought, "Wait a minute, why am I doing this at all?" so I'm specifically looking for a pre-existing library. (Or at least a good set of pre-existing test cases) Otherwise I can do this on my own, but it's a big pain.

Comment: Unless you find a sweet library, I think whatever you do is going to be ugly and hard to read.

Comment: Yeah, I know. How does one entice the Java demigods at Google or Oracle or IBM or Apache or whatever to make a good non-viral open-source library to do this? It's a missing chunk of Java reflection, IMHO. I can come up with something that works for my own purposes, but I think it would be far from perfect, in either correctness / documentation / maintainability.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read [this blog post](http://www.cowtowncoder.com/blog/archives/2010/12/entry_436.html) and check out [ClassMate](https://github.com/cowtowncoder/java-classmate). It should do most of the grungy work for you.

Comment: ARGH! So promising, but it's slightly different -- it resolves generic types, but doesn't do anything for method resolution. But at least it's a start, and I bet I could cajole the authors into extending it.

Answer (score 2):

Commons beanutils have this function for finding matching methods:
[getMatchingAccessibleMethod](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/api/org/apache/commons/beanutils/MethodUtils.html#getMatchingAccessibleMethod%28java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%5b%5d%29)

It works with primitive types but it is somewhat indeterministic as the docs says.

Comment: Note that in `getMatchingAccessibleMethod` the primitive matching is one way - parameter `Long.class` will match `foo(long)` but `Long.TYPE` won't match `foo(Long)`

Comment: +1: @Bengt: what a relief to find out Apache's got some tools, maybe not what I wanted, but something at least.

Answer (score 0):

One of the users on guava-discuss recommended I look at the [Mirror library](http://projetos.vidageek.net/mirror).

Unfortunately it doesn't handle overloading resolution either, at least not at present.

Answer (score -1):

I've had some success with MVEL and properties, but I can't recall whether it can dispatch method calls.

However, you might be looking for different language entirely. Given the nature of the problem, I suggest taking a look at Groovy, which integrates very cleanly with Java.

Comment: hmm, I'm "stuck" with Java for various reasons, the biggest one being maintainability (adding a different language significantly constrains my ability to get help from other developers)