# Java reflection: how do the Method.getGenericXXXXX methods work?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I just noticed there's a [`Method.getGenericReturnType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericReturnType%28%29) as well as [`Method.getReturnType()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getReturnType%28%29) and similar pairs for exception types and parameter types.

I thought generics in Java worked via type erasure. So how would these methods work at runtime? (and what would I use them for at runtime?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Generics that have concrete types part of declarations (methods, fields, classes, arguments) are retained.

So you can obtain the types from this declaration

```
 public List<String> toString(List<Foo> foos) { .. }
```

But you can't from this code:

```
public List<E> transform(List<E> list) {
  // E is not accessible at runtime
}
```

Comment: weird... so if I'm doing runtime method dispatch (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021109/java-runtime-method-resolution) then I have to worry about this aspect too?

Comment: (don't you need an `<E>` before `List<E>` in your 2nd example?)

Comment: I assumed E is part of the class declaration, but it may be in the method too.

Answer (score 1):

Generics may work by erasure, but code which uses your compiled classes still need to use generics correctly.  There is additional information there for the compiler, which you can get, but this doesn't change its runtime behaviour.