# Java reflection anyway to compare Class<?> or Type to Class<T>?

Tags: java, reflection, type-erasure

Forgive me for asking such a question but I have been doing C# for the past couple years until very recently so I am a little rusty on type erasure generics in Java compared to the intuitive version of generics in C#.

I have a situation like so:

```
public void doSomething(Class<T> classType) {
  for (Method method : classType.getMethods()) {
    for (Class<?> parameterClass : method.getParameterTypes()) {
      // How do I compare parameterClass to classType or to String.class?
    }
  }
}
```

Since parameterClass is of type Class then it is an unknown class type thus it can't be determined at runtime?  Does their exist a way to perform this comparison?  Again I aplogize I haven't used Java generics in years and I have been reading up on it and am still confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`method.getGenericParameterTypes()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#getGenericParameterTypes%28%29) instead of the non-generic `getParameterTypes()`

Comment: oh, wait -- you just need to compare types; `getGenericParameterTypes()` is when you actually want to determine the type parameter, assuming it's available.

Comment: This returns an array of Type, which Class implements.  Why is this a better idea?

Comment: This is where I am confused, how can you COMPARE Types yet not be able to determine the Type parameter?

Comment: @maple_shaft: either you can compare types or you cannot. It depends on what erasure erases. I asked this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021179/java-reflection-how-do-the-method-getgenericxxxxx-methods-work

Comment: Brilliant!  This is why `.equals` for generic Class objects seems to work, because the types were concrete when they were compiled.  If this didn't occur then generics would be useless.  Thanks!