# Java: Get method with interface parameter with its implementation

Tags: java, reflection

I would like to call method(using reflection) which has parameter Interface - i.e: List but with implementation of List.
For example:

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchMethodException {
        Method method = Test1.class.getMethod("method", new Class[]{ArrayList.class});

    }

    public class Test1 {

        public void method(List list) {
            System.out.println("method");
        }
    }
}
```

I get `NoSuchMethodException`. In this case i know which params i get, problem is that I want to use this in general when i don't "statically" know param types.

Is possible that getMethod returns also method which has interface as parameter? Or i have to write my own "methodsearcher"

Thank you.

**EDIT:**
It's much more complicated. I'm trying to write something like "dynamic modular architecture" in my program. I have Core, which should comunicate with other modules. So i don't know params classes in programming time but in runtime.

```
 public Object processMessage(String target, String methodName, List<Object> params, Object returnNonExist) {
    Module m = modules.get(target);
    if (m == null) {
        return returnNonExist;
    } else {
        Class[] paramsTypes = new Class[params.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < params.size(); i++) {
            paramsTypes[i] = params.get(i).getClass();
            }
        }
        try {
            Method method = m.getClass().getMethod(methodName, paramsTypes);
            Object result = method.invoke(m, params.toArray());
            return result;
        }
```

Is it better?

Comment: why do you want to do that? There is no method in Test 1 that takes ArrayList as argument and so you dont get one.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2580665/java-getmethod-with-superclass-parameters-in-method

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I probably found solution - I have to write my own "method searcher" which respect interface implementation and superclases. It looks like this:

```
public static Method findMethod(Object m, String methodName, Class[] paramsTypes) {
    Method[] metody = m.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
    List<Method> sameNames = new ArrayList<Method>();
    // filter other names
    for (Method meth : metody) {
        if (meth.getName().equals(methodName)) {
            sameNames.add(meth);
        }
    }
    // lets find best candidate
    if (sameNames.isEmpty()) {
        return null;
    } else {
        // filter other count of parameters
        List<Method> sameCountOfParameters = new ArrayList<Method>();
        for (Method meth : sameNames) {
            if (meth.getParameterTypes().length == paramsTypes.length) {
                sameCountOfParameters.add(meth);
            }
        }
        if (sameCountOfParameters.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        } else {
            for (Method meth : sameCountOfParameters) {
                // first one, which is suitable is the best
                Class<?>[] params = meth.getParameterTypes();
                boolean good = true;
                for (int i = 0; i < params.length && good; i++) {
                    if (params[i].isInterface() && Arrays.asList(paramsTypes[i].getInterfaces()).contains(params[i])) {
                        //if i-th paramater type is Interface and we search method with its implementation
                        good = true;
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        // if we call it with subclass and parameter typ is superclass
                        if (paramsTypes[i].getSuperclass().equals(params[i])) {
                            good = true;
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                    good = false;
                }
                if (good) {
                    return meth;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

I'am using this after standard getMethod throws "NoSuchMethodException" (It is in about 5% cases, so i don't care about speed.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `List` class, not `ArrayList`.

```
Method method = Test1.class.getMethod("method", new Class[]{List.class});
```

Answer (score 1):

Great answer from @radeczek. I extended it to work on subclasses ...

```
    public Method findMethod(String name, Class<?>[] paramsTypes) {
        
        Method[] methods = object.getClass().getMethods();
        
        List<Method> sameNames = new ArrayList<Method>();
        
        // filter other names
        for (Method m : methods) {
            if (m.getName().equals(name)) {
                sameNames.add(m);
            }
        }
        
        // lets find best candidate
        if (sameNames.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
            
        } else {
            
            // filter other count of parameters
            List<Method> sameCountOfParameters = new ArrayList<Method>();
            for (Method m : sameNames) {
                
                if (m.getParameterTypes().length == paramsTypes.length) {
                    sameCountOfParameters.add(m);
                }
            }
            
            if (sameCountOfParameters.isEmpty()) {
                return null;
                
                
            } else {
                for (Method m : sameCountOfParameters) {
                    
                    // first one, which is suitable is the best
                    Class<?>[] params = m.getParameterTypes();
                    
                    boolean good = true;
                    
                    for (int i = 0; i < params.length && good; i++) {
                        
                        // Recurse into subclasses 
                        good = findSubclass(paramsTypes[i],params[i]);
                    }
                    if (good) {
                        return m;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
    
    /**
     * Recursive check for interfaces of superclasses. 
     * 
     * @param paramType
     * @param param
     * @return
     */
    private boolean findSubclass(Class<?> paramType, Class<?> param) {
        
        if (param.isInterface() && Arrays.asList(paramType.getInterfaces()).contains(param)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            
            if (paramType.getSuperclass() != null) {
                return findSubclass(paramType.getSuperclass(), param);
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }
```